# How handle error when i Create user auth with php

Tags: php, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I use this code below to create user Authentication and it works but sometimes there are some problems happen to like the same email same phone number etc.that cause crash in the app can anyone help me to handle this kind of error

```
 $userProperties = [
                'email' => $data["Email"],
                'emailVerified' => false,
                'password' => $data["Password"],
                'displayName' => $data["Name"],
                'photoUrl' => '',
                'disabled' => false,
                "uid" => $uid
            ];
    
            $createdUser = self::$auth->createUser($userProperties);
```

Comment: If you're getting duplicate errors, the request shouldn't be made at all; there should be validations that catch those issues (and other ones you can know ahead of time, like null or incomplete data) and reply with a meaningful response explaining why the request couldn't be fulfilled.

Comment: That being said, you should try/catch any exceptions, and reply accordingly. You just don't want to rely only on exceptions to communicate invalid request issues back to the requestor.

Comment: you mean i need first to check before do request if this email is valid or not

Comment: Yes, for instance a username should be checked to see if it's been used and reply with an error about that to the requestor. Requests to make internal state changes (like adding a user, updating a user's phone number, or removing the user) should only be made once the request itself has been proved to be a viable change.

Comment: Also, validations that protect the resource integrity of your site should always be done on the server. Doing validation in the browser is in effect only a warning, e.g. "if this request were made, it would not work". In the browser, validations do not technically protect anything but the user's time and level of annoyance. Which is good, but do the server-side ones first.